# Is there a way to make a realtime ForEach in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, foreach, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using [ForEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) to populate my HTML table.

So far so good but the table is not realtime. I have to reload the function for it to fetch the results again. If I add or delete an entry nothing happens VISUALLY until I reload.

Is there a way to make this realtime?
Code from Firebase Docs:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
  var key = childSnapshot.key;
  // childData will be the actual contents of the child
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
});
});
```

Please excuse my poor knowledge on JS, I am working on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `once()` you're telling that database that you only want to get the current value and don't care about updates.

The solution to get realtime updates, is to use `on()`. Since a promise can only resolve once while an `on()` handler is called for every update, you should use a callback with `on()`:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    // childData will be the actual contents of the child
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

If you care about updating a UI in response to such updates, you'll probably want to use `child_` handlers. These get called one level lower in your JSON tree, so in your case for each user that is added/changed/deleted. This allows you to update the UI more directly. For example, the `child_added` event for the above could be:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key;
    var data = snapshot.val();
    // TODO: add an element to the UI with the value and id=key
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Now you can handle the other events with:

```
query.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  // TODO: update the element with id=key in the update to match snapshot.val();
})
query.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
  // TODO: remove the element with id=key from the UI
})
```

This and much more is covered pretty extensively in our [guide for web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) and in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).

Comment: Thank you so much. Again, please excuse my poor JS.